# Is this Kabocha squash bad?

Tags: food-safety, squash, ripe

I just cut open Kabocha that I picked up yesterday at the farmers market and noticed some strange spots. Is this ok to cook?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No this not ok to cook because it looks like that it is rotten.

Comment: I'd agree ... there's some sort of decay going on there if the uncooked flesh isn't uniform in color.